# Can Horizontal Pod Scaling work with one node only?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm new to **Kubernetes**, and I have a doubt about **horizontal pod autoscaling**. Can I apply HPA with just one node ? If so, what are the benefits of HPA using one node only ?

If I use the metrics below, the target says `averageUtilization` 50% of cpu. Does that imply that I need a new node after the value is reached ?

```
metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 50
```

Any advice ?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some notes that might help you to sort things out:

Yes, you can use horizontal pod autoscaling on one node only.

The benefit of running multiple pods is parallelism: More instances of your app can handle more load - in that regard it doesn't matter if you run the pods on one or several nodes.

But if you have more pods of your application, you might end up in a situation where you need additional nodes to handle the load.

To determine out how many pods can run on one node, kubernetes uses the concept of [resource limits and requests](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/).

HPA will spawn new pods if the actual utilization of your pod hits the target utilization - but it doesn't take care that your node can handle more pods - you need to configure this using resource limits and requests.

Scaling up the nodes of your cluster is not handled by HPA, you need to use the [kubernetes cluster autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler) for that.

Comment: That's helpfull, thank you so much @stackoverflowjakob